# Sticky WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-animation, doubleanimation

I am trying to create Sticky WPF window.

If window nearer left stick to left or stick right if nearer to right **else** stick to top

Below the code I am using,

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                this.DragMove();
            }

    private void Window_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {                
                Point currentPoints = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));

//Place left
                if (currentPoints.X < (300))
                {                 
                    DoubleAnimation moveAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(-190, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, moveAnimation);
                }
//Place Right
                else if (currentPoints.X > (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 300))
                {
                    DoubleAnimation moveAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width + 190, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, moveAnimation);              
                }
//Place top
                else
                {
                    DoubleAnimation TopAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(-190, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, TopAnimation, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
                }
            }
```

The above code moves window only once.

on MSDN, [How to: Set a Property After Animating It with a Storyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493(v=vs.110).aspx)

To run animation again, set BeginAnimation Property to NULL,

I tried setting the property to NULL before animation.
And the code now works fine.

Now the code looks like

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point currentPoints = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));

            if (currentPoints.X < (300))
            {
                if (_MyWindow.HasAnimatedProperties)
                    _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, null);
                DoubleAnimation moveAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(-190, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, moveAnimation);
            }
            else if (currentPoints.X > (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 300))
            {
                if (_MyWindow.HasAnimatedProperties)
                    _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, null);
                DoubleAnimation moveAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width + 190, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, moveAnimation);
            }
            else
            {
                if (_MyWindow.HasAnimatedProperties)
                    _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, null);
                DoubleAnimation TopAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(-190, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, TopAnimation, HandoffBehavior.Compose);
            }
        }
```

If Noticed, I am placing window at -190 position at left and top to hide some of its part.

But using 
Below property, Its resetting the window position to 0.
I dont want it to reset the position

```
_MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.LeftProperty, null);
```

Can anybody suggest how to do multiple animation without resetting existing position?

- Ashish Sapkale

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea of setting LeftProperty to null is right but you should be doing that after the animation is finished.

So add a delegate to your animation and set the property to null in that and see if it works.

example

```
TopAnimation.Completed += (s,e) =>
{
   _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, null);
};
```

Your other options are to use ThicknessAnimation or TranslateTransform to move your window. Let me know if you are still having problems

Comment: Actually main problem is that whenever I call, _MyWindow.BeginAnimation(Window.TopProperty, null);

It resets its top position to 0.

In my case I want to keep my window at -190 top